# C Programming ? using pointers

Tags: c, syntax

My teacher gave us a question in programming class today and I don't understand how he got the answer. I was hoping someone could explain it to me. We basically have to show what the programs output would be, however I am somewhat confused as to how to get the answer to the question. The Question is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void  do_something (int , int * );

    int main (void)
    {
        int first = 1, second = 2 ;
        do_something(second, &first);
        printf("%4d%4d\n", first, second);
        return (0);
    }

    void  do_something (int thisp, int *that)
    {
        int the_other;
        the_other = 5;
        thisp = 2 + the_other;
        *that = the_other * thisp;
        return;
    }
```

Answer

```
   35 and 2
```

Comment: Which line you did not understood ?

Comment: Use a debugger (if you know how to use it, possibly through an IDE), execute the program step by step, and examine what's going on. Or insert print commands.

Comment: @Nick: I think the function definition will be `void do_somthing(int this, int *thatp);` not the otherway around.

Comment: basically what is messing me up is the * , and im not exactly sure how he reached the answer of 35 and 2.

Comment: @Nick; Read [pointers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) or better read [this](http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Comment: @legends2k: Although I agree, this is just names and won't change the result.

Comment: @alk: True for a machine, but it'll change the understanding for a human, would help a beginner, I guess :)

Comment: @haccks ... or watch the classic: http://www.cs.stanford.edu/cslibrary/PointerFunCBig.avi (from: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/)

Comment: @alk; Oh yes! That's even better. My favorite [**Binky's Pointer video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thisp = 2 + the_other;
*that = the_other * thisp;
```

Means:

```
thisp = 2 + 5
*that = 5 * 7
```

And `that` contains address of `first` in main which is overwritten in `do_something` as 35. `Second` remains 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The function `do_something` contains 2 parameters.

1. normal integer (thisp)
2. pointer to an integer. (that)

What your teacher wanted you to learn is, **pass by value** and **pass by address.**

In pass by value, the original value doesn't change. This is because in the example given.
value of variable `second` is copied `thisp` variable.

In pass by address, the original value can be modified within the function. 
This is because, the pointer `that` is pointing to the location of variable `first`. So if value of `that` is changed, the value of `first` will also change.

**This is why, value of `first` is changed in the output and value of `second` is unaffected.**

Comment: There is no `pass by reference` in `C`. The object always creates a copy. Wrong explanation.

Comment: My apologies, I meant pass by address.